# Visual Studio Code not finding any TS or node packages

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I installed node and tsc with homebrew on MacOs.  I installed one package with npm.

I am trying to build with Visual Studio Code.  The node/TS code I am building is a Visual Studio extension.  I did not write it and am not modifying it.

Visual Studio Code can't find any packages.  I can't tell from the messages where it is even looking.  I believe that most of the packages are installed in ~/node_modules. Maybe 1-2 are missing, but everything is reported missing so the package resolution is not working.

There is probably something missing or incorrect in the project files as it was setup to run on any number of machines.  I don't even know what files I should show you.

the most basic would seem to be:  tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        // "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode-test"
    ]
}
```

I added the moduleResolution statement but it did nothing, so commented it out.  The ts source files are indeed in a subdirectory of the project folder called src.  But, we are not getting that far.

I have looked at a bunch of documentation related to building Typescript to node projects in VS Code, but none are plain dumb stupid as I am.  None seem to address this most basic problem to find the packages.  I think my installation is pretty standard.

There has to be something wrong in the project (because it was meant to be built on any machine) or in my VS Code config or both.

I really need some total beginner help on just getting started.

Comment: you should show exact error messages of this error: "Visual Studio Code can't find any packages", also please write where do this messages appear or how do you know it cannot find them.

Comment: Also, do you really mean "Visual Studio extension" and not "Visual Studio Code extension"?

Comment: Run `tsc` with the `--traceResolution` option to find out where TypeScript is looking for the modules.